# Parsing XML file from local hard disk using DOM in Android

Tags: android, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

How to parse xml file from hard disk using DOM? Codes can be a good help..

```
InputStream catDoc = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.testingxml);
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
dom = builder.parse(catDoc, null);
```

What is context here?? I don't understand much..please help..
I'm a beginner here so...

Comment: see answer given by me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089291/how-to-parse-xml-in-android/10090154#10090154

Comment: Android itself has a XML Parser .

Comment: i mean from C:,but thanks for reply..I just get it now. I added the xml file in the res/raw folder and its done..

Answer (score 0):

The context in that line of code is the calling activity's context. Basically it represents the resources allocated to your application. Beyond that your question is too vague to answer directly, perhaps visiting the google tutorials to learn how android works first would suit your needs. [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i'm newbie here so i need more tutorials. can you give me some links for me to learn from?
maybe about preferences/settings in android?Thanks a lot!

Comment: The link I gave you covers everything. It is google's official documentation. It can be a bit dense though so one other that I have found useful is http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#tutorial_preferences Just remember that odds are good someone has put it on the internet, so if you have a question google whatever it is you are trying to do plus tutorial. For example, this question googled with "parse xml using DOM in android tutorial" returns a huge number of good examples.